# MVC 4 - Displaying HTML vs. Straight Text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 View where the user can enter straight text or HTML into a text area control. When this text is displayed, I use `@HTML.Raw()` to display it. If the user entered HTML, everything displays based on the HTML. If he/she didn't all the line breaks are ignored and the text just runs together.

So, what I would like to do is to somehow test to see if the user entered HTML or straight text. If straight text, when displaying the text, I'd like to replace all the line break characters with an HTML break tag to maintain the formatting.

1. Is there a somewhat reliable way to detect if the text contains
   HTML?
2. Is there a better/easier way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a somewhat reliable way to detect if the text contains HTML?

Not really. The problem becomes hardest when someone is writing a plain text enter that discusses HTML.

> Is there a better/easier way to do what I'm trying to do?

I quite like Stackoverflow's approach. Just use markdown and provide clear instructions on how to use it beside the editing window.

Comment: I mean "do what Stackoverflow does". See also [markdown](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=markdown).